# La consola de Firebase Cloud Message no envia los mensajes a mi app android

Tags: android, firebase-messaging

he seguido los pasos para añadir firebase cloud message a mi app de android y al hacer la prueba enviando un mensaje desde firebase console no llega la notificación a mi aplicación, no se si alguien sabe porque.

He probado a poner el mensaje en un tag sobreescribiendo el metodo onMessageReceived y no aparece nada.

He conseguido que me devuelva el token pero no recibir el mensaje que envio a través de la consola de notificaciones de firebase.

FirebaseMessagingService

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {



override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
    val TAG = "tokenFirebase"
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.exception)
            return@OnCompleteListener
        }

        // Get new FCM registration token
        val token = task.result

        // Log and toast
        Log.d(TAG, "Token recibido($token)")
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Token recibido($token)", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    })
}

}
```

Este seria mi manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tfgclienttaller">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".framework.MainApp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TFGClientTaller">
    <activity
        android:name=".framework.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TFGClientTaller">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".data.sources.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

**Editado** : He conseguido que me envie las notificaciones solo que tardan como 1 minuto, hay alguna razón para que pase esto?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Dónde está tu método `onMessageReceived()`? Es desde él que podrás recibir los mensajes, mostrarlos, etc. Revisa [la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#kotlin+ktx) y los ejemplos allí indicados.

Comment: el metodo onMessageReceived() lo tengo comentado, no lo he puesto en el codigo porque teoricamente segun la documentacion no es necesario para recibir una notificacion desde la consola, muchas gracias

Comment: Sobre el tiempo que tardan los mensajes en llegar, [lee lo que dice la doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl), depende del nivel de prioridad que hayas indicado y de otros factores.